# Wifi not connecting on Ubuntu after I closed my laptop

Tags: wireless, rfkill

Wifi did not connect after I clicked 'suspend', closed my computer, and then opened my computer. I rebooted the computer. I upgraded my ubuntu to Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS but it is still not working. I did `rfkill list` which showed

`3: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes`

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem and will answer my own question. I shut the screen down, pulled it up. I then clicked 'suspend' and then turned it on by pressing any key. After a few seconds the wifi connected and my `rfkill list` now outputs

`3: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no`